# Make a UIView display the camera view using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to display the image a the camera sees into my own custom view. I DO NOT want to use Apple's own overlay property for UIImagePickerController: cameraOverlayView.

I don't want an overlay, but for it to just display in my particular view. The only way I've been able to do it was creating a subview in my UIView, but doing this doesn't allow me to use any of my own custom buttons I've made over my UIView . My code so far is:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

[imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[imagePickerController setShowsCameraControls:NO];
[imagePickerController setEditing:NO];
[imagePickerController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[self.videoPreviewView addSubview:[imagePickerController view]];
[imagePickerController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

where videoPreviewView is the outlet for my UIView!

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: are your custom Buttons recognizing touches, have u created Action for those buttons.?

Comment: @Bonnie Yes. I have created actions for all the buttons and they do recognise touches. When I implement an overlay however, they do not!

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it your way myself, but I also wanted to create a custom camera view. This might not be what you are looking for, but it is an alternative. I created a custom UIView together with .xib file.

In the .m file you just call the appropriate delegate methods to the ViewController where you instantiated the imagePicker. In this ViewController you then call appropriate methods like `takePicture`.

This way you can make the overlay look any way you like with the xib file. You can instantiate the image picker

```
    FALKCameraView.h :

        @protocol CameraViewDelegate <NSObject>

        - (void)cameraPressed;

        - (void)buttonPressed;
        //etc


        @end

        @interface FALKCameraView : UIView

        @property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject<CameraViewDelegate> *delegate;

        //Camera Button pressed- notifies CameraViewDelegate
        - (IBAction)cameraPressed:(id)sender;
        //Button pressed - notifies CameraViewDelegate
        -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;


        @end

    FALKCameraView.m:

    @implementation FALKCameraView

    @synthesize delegate;

    - (IBAction)cameraPressed:(id)sender{
        [delegate cameraPressed];
    }

    -(IBAction)buttonnPressed:(id)sender{
        [delegate buttonPressed];
    }


    @end


    FALKCameraViewController.h:

    @interface FALKCameraViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, CameraViewDelegate>

    - (void)cameraPressed;

    - (void)buttonPressed;

    @end


    FALKCameraViewController.m:

    @interface FALKCameraViewController
         @property (strong,nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    @end

    @implementation FALKCameraViewController
    @synthesise imagePicker;

    -(void)setUpCamera{
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
                imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                imagePicker.delegate = self;
                imagePicker.sourceType =
                UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
                imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;


imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];



                NSString *nibName = @"FALKCameraView";

                NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                                              owner:nil
                                                            options:nil];
                if([nibs count]){
                    id nib = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
                    if([nib isKindOfClass:[FALKCameraView class]]){
                        FALKCameraView *view = (FALKCameraView*)nib;
                        view.delegate = self;
                        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = view;
                    }
                }

                [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                                   animated:NO completion:nil];
            }
    }



        -(void)cameraPressed:(id)sender{
               [imagePicker takePicture];
        }

    @end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm using storyboard... Does that make a difference? I tried implementing it though and I'm getting an error at the line: imagePicker.cameraView = view;  In my code, what do I need to replace cameraView with? Like the viewcontroller name? Thanks very much for your help though!

Comment: I also use story board for the rest of my project, you are still able to load from a custom .xib file. What sort of error are you getting? Did you create the seperate UIView subclass with it's own .xib file etc? "CameraView" is what I named the custom UIView I created.

Comment: So you should have: CameraView.h, CameraView.m and CameraView.xib. Just leave the UI in the xib empty for now and make sure to set the class of the view in the xib to CameraView.

Comment: oh right ok two things: You need to implement the protocol 'CameraViewDelegate' in your view controller - this is the protocol I gave you above in the '.h' file code. Now the second error - the name of the property does not change. If you called your custom 'UIView' 'FALKCameraView', then the code should read: 'imagePicker.cameraView = view;' just as it does above. 'cameraView' is a built-in property of 'imagePicker', you don't change that. Whereas 'view' is a variable in the code above that is instantiated to '(CameraView*)nib' so if you called your

Comment: custom UIView 'FalkCameraView' then you would instantiate it to that. Just substitute 'CameraView' to 'FalkCameraView' in the code above. :)

Comment: edited above to include your names. If you stick that code into four files FALKCameraView.h/m and FALKCameraViewController.h/m and create a  FALKCameraView.xib and in the xib you change the class to FALKCameraView it should work!

Comment: I don't know why but it's still making errors! I have it exactly as you had it. I just changed cameraView to cameraOverlayView as I believe that is the correct property after thoroughly reading the documentation. Even after that though it isn't working and I don't know why! I'm probably just going to use the AV Foundation Framework as that is the only way I can get it working! Thanks very much for all your effort though. If no answer appears in 1 day I'll mark yours as the answer!

Comment: oh yes, you are totally right, that is the correct property name ;) What errors are you getting? I wrote that code into SO directly, it's not checked, maybe I can help you solve the error

Comment: It isn't showing any errors now, but lots of warnings. Plus, the It comes up with an error when I click on the button. I think it's going to be too difficult to explain over SO but thanks for offering though! You've been really helpful mate. I'll see if I can get it working though!

Comment: you're welcome! added one missing line above: imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage]; good luck.

Comment: have you found an alternative solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will work and i just added a single view you can add any custom object to overlayview of the picker

```
   if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    NSString *nibName = @"CameraView";

    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName
                                                  owner:nil
                                                options:nil];
    if([nibs count]){
        id nib = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        if([nib isKindOfClass:[CameraView class]]){
            CameraView *view = (CameraView*)nib;
            view.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = view;
        }
    }

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also tried to implement that. I didn't really want one with an overlay, but I'm trying it out anyway. It came up with an error at `Utils`. I tried searching it but I still have no idea what it is or what it does... Do I have to replace it in my code or do you have any idea why it's errorring? Cheers :)